# Quartic Equation Solution and Conditions for real roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Q1. How to solve a Quartic Equation. There is [an online calculator](http://www.1728.org/quartic.htm) available (and many more similar) that gives the precise answers and also defines the method. Does anyone know what the source of this method is?

Q2. Given a Quartic Equation

$$
ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0\,,
$$
what are the conditions for the existence of real roots of the above equation?
Any reference material?

Comment: Plese see. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescartesSignRule.html.

Comment: You still haven't read [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2972804)? I notice that you asked [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92689) months ago...

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/786/72

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/21481/abhinav
http://math.stackexchange.com/users/26124/abhinav

Are both of these your account?

Answer (score 5):

What about a set of expressions in the quartic's coefficients that discriminate between all cases?
There are 9 cases:

1. 4 distinct real roots.
2. 3 distinct real roots with one of them being a double root.
3. 2 distinct double roots both real.
4. Triple root and and a distinct fourth root.
5. Quadruple root.
6. 2 distinct real roots and two complex roots.
7. double real root and 2 complex roots.
8. 2 double roots both complex.
9. four distinct complex roots.

Such sets are known for quadratic and cubic polynomials:

Quadratic ($ ax^2+bx+c $):

Discriminant: $b^2-4ac$

Positive for two distinct real roots, zero for double root, and negative for complex conjugate roots.

Cubic ($ ax^3+bx^2+cx+d $):

$\Delta_1=2b^3-9abc+27a^2d$ and $\Delta_2=\Delta_1^2-4(b^2-3ac)^3$.

Then:

$ \Delta_2>0 $ gives one real root and two complex roots.

$ \Delta_2<0$ gives three distinct real roots.

$ \Delta_2=0 $ but $ \Delta_1\neq 0$ gives a double root plus one different root.

$ \Delta_1=\Delta_2=0$ gives a triple root.

Answer (score 3):

The method is based on a paper by Herbert E. Salzer "A Note on the Solution of Quartic Equations" (Am. Math Society Proceedings, 1959).

Suppose there is an equation $X^4+AX^3+BX^2+CX+D=0$, with real or complex roots $X_1$, $X_2$,  $X_3$,  $X_4$.

First, solve the cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ where $a=1$, $b=-B$, $c=AC-4D$, $d=D(4B-A^2)-C^2$; only 1 real root is needed, call it $x_1$.

Find $m=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}A^2-B+x_1}$, and  $n=\frac{Ax_1-2C}{4m}$.

If m=0, take $n=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}x_1^2-D}$.

Proceed to the *case I* or *case II* depending on whether m is real or imaginary.

***Case I.*** $m$ is real;

Let $\alpha=(\frac{1}{2}A^2-x_1-B)$ and $\beta=4n-Am$

$\gamma=\sqrt{\alpha+\beta}$ and $\delta=\sqrt{\alpha-\beta}$.

With the above notations

$X_1=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}A+m+\gamma}{2}$,
$X_2=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}A-m+\delta}{2}$,
$X_3=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}A+m-\gamma}{2}$, 
$X_4=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}A-m-\delta}{2}$.

***Case II.*** $m$ is imaginary.
Take $m=im'$, then $n$ is also imaginary, take $n=in'$;

Let $\alpha=(\frac{1}{2}A^2-x_1-B)$ and $\beta=4n'-Am'$

$\rho=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$, $\gamma=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha+\rho}{2}}$ and $\delta=\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}$.

Then,

$X_1=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}A+\gamma+i(m'+\delta)}{2}$, $X_2=\bar{X_1}$,

$X_3=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}A-\gamma+i(m'-\delta)}{2}$, $X_4=\bar{X_3}$

if $\gamma=0$ then $\alpha=-\alpha', \alpha'\ge 0$, and formaulae above still hold provided that $\delta$ is replaced by $\sqrt{\alpha'}$.

This solution is easily programmed as opposed to the tedious formulae by Cardano-Ferrari.

Below is a MATLAB function producing REAL roots only (if there are any) based on this method.

%returns r1,r2,r3,r4: REAL if roots are real, ZERO if complex

% isreal1, isreal2, isreal3, isreal4 - logical (or bit), 1 (true) - if root is real, 0 (false) - if root is complex

function [r1, r2, r3, r4, isreal1, isreal2, isreal3, isreal4 ] = quarticsolve_salzer(a4,a3,a2,a1,a0)

%initialisation

r1=0;

r2=0;

r3=0;

r4=0;

isreal1=0;

isreal2=0;

isreal3=0;

isreal4=0;

a=a3/a4;

b=a2/a4;

c=a1/a4;

d=a0/a4;

%First, find 1 real root of a cubic equation

%$x^3-bx^2+(ac-4d)x+d(4b-a^2)-c^2$

x1=cubsolve_1realroot(1,-b,a*c-4*d,d*(4*b-a^2)-c^2);

%this routine is a modified version of solution found [there](http://www.helioscorner.com/numerical-solution-of-a-cubic-equation-which-is-the-fastest-way/)

m2=0.25*a*a-b+x1;

if(m2>0)

```
m=sqrt(0.25*a^2-b+x1);

n=(a*x1-2*c)/4/m;
```

elseif(m2==0)

```
m=0;

n=sqrt(0.25*x1^2-d);
```

else

```
%imaginary roots only

% r1,r2,r3,r4 are returned 0, isreal1,2,3,4 returned false (or 0)
```

return;

end;

alpha=0.5*a^2-x1-b;

beta=4*n-a*m;

if(alpha+beta>=0)

%two real roots are produced

gamma=sqrt(alpha+beta);

r1=-0.25*a+0.5*m+0.5*gamma;

r2=-0.25*a+0.5*m-0.5*gamma;

isreal1=1;

isreal2=1;

end;

if(alpha-beta>=0)

%another pair of real roots produced

delta=sqrt(alpha-beta);

r3=-0.25*a-0.5*m+0.5*delta;

r4=-0.25*a-0.5*m-0.5*delta;

isreal3=1;

isreal4=1;

end;

return;

end

function [x1]=cubsolve_1realroot(a3,a2,a1,a0)

a=a2/a3;
b=a1/a3;
c=a0/a3;

Q=(a^2-3*b)/9;
R=(2*a^3-9*a*b+27*c)/54;
R2=R^2;
Q3=Q^3;
if (R2

A=-(abs(R)+sqrt(R2-Q3))^(1/3);
if (R < 0)
A=-A; %If we used A=A*sign(R) then if R=0 => sign(R)=0 => A=0 which is wrong
end
if (A==0)
B=0;
else
B=Q/A;
end
AB=A+B;
x1=AB-a/3;
end

Comment: could you please explain your method instead of giving a row code. This would be much more helpful for the next readers

Comment: I voted this answer because it is just what I was looking for. There are reams of stuff about algebraic solutions to quartic equations, but none as computationally elegant as Salzer's method, which I was able to code and debug in less than an hour. So thanks, Antonm ....

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple search method that always works for the count or estimatica roots. In general it is a rough approximation $a$ of the root $x$ is used the bisection method. And it applies the method of$x_0=a\quad x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ Newton for the bestapproximation of root. That is, $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=root$. On more times, $|x_{10}-root|<0.01$.

Another method of counting real roots escartes beyond the rule and that is easy to see geometrically is to rank the extreme points of the equation with maximum, minimum and saddle point.

1) We know the fundamental theorem algebra that the number of roots of this equation is at most equal to four.

2)Let $ x $ is a point that extreme point ($ f '(x) = 0 $):


If $ x $ is the point of minimum ($ f'' (x)> 0 $) and satisfies $ f (x)> 0 $ then the equation has two complex roots.


 If $ x $ is the maximum point ($ f'' (x) <0 $) and satisfies $ f (x) <0 $ then the equation has two complex roots.

If $ x $ is the point of cell $ f'' (x) = 0 $ and $ f (x) = 0 $ then $ x $ is double root of the equation.

3) You can also use the Intermediate Value Theorem ([See wikipedia][1]) to verify the existence of roots in a reiais interestimar the interval $ [a, b] $. In fact, if $f(a)<0<f(b)$ ou $f(b)>0>f(a)$, then there is a x ∈ [a, b] such that f(x) = 0.

Comment: the method that online calculator describes is not iterative and is strangely analytic. any ideas how the calculator is obtaining roots of a quartic equation directly just like solving a quadratic equation without computing any iterations?

Comment: The method which the calculator applies is reported at http://www.1728.org/quartic2.htm

Comment: Then see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB function to solve the general case quartic equation (based on the full formula from Wikipedia). Unfortunately, it does not determine which roots are real (I am working on that now).

```
function [r1, r2, r3, r4]=quarticsolve(a4,a3,a2,a1,a0)
%solving quartic equation

    a=a3/a4;
    b=a2/a4;
    c=a1/a4;
    d=a0/a4;

    third=1.0/3.0;
    root3=2^third;

    q1=(b*b-3*a*c+12*d);
    q2=2*b*b*b-9*a*b*c+27*c*c+27*a*a*d-72*b*d;
    q3=-4*q1*q1*q1+q2*q2;
    q4=-a*a*a+4*a*b-8*c;

    s0=0.25*a*a-2*b*third;
    s1=root3*q1*third/(q2+sqrt(q3))^third;
    s2=((q2+sqrt(q3))/54)^third;

    r1=-0.25*a-0.5*sqrt(s0+s1+s2)-0.5*sqrt(2*s0-s1-s2-0.25*q4/sqrt(s0+s1+s2));
    r2=-0.25*a-0.5*sqrt(s0+s1+s2)+0.5*sqrt(2*s0-s1-s2-0.25*q4/sqrt(s0+s1+s2));
    r3=-0.25*a+0.5*sqrt(s0+s1+s2)-0.5*sqrt(2*s0-s1-s2+0.25*q4/sqrt(s0+s1+s2));
    r4=-0.25*a+0.5*sqrt(s0+s1+s2)+0.5*sqrt(2*s0-s1-s2+0.25*q4/sqrt(s0+s1+s2));
end
```

Comment: The MathJax tutorials beckon...

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to solve the equation
$$x^{4}+ax^{2}+bx+c=0.$$
It is possible to factor this polynomial into two polynomials of degree 2.

In order for us to have zero coefficient for $x^{3}$ , and the free term to be equal to c, we must have a factorization of the form
$$x^{4}+ax^{2}+bx+c=\left(x^{2}+\alpha x+\beta\right)\left(x^{2}-\alpha x +\frac{c}{\beta}\right)=0.$$
Equating the coefficients we get
$$a=\frac{c}{\beta}+\beta-\alpha^{2}$$
$$b/\alpha=\frac{c}{\beta}-\beta.$$
or

$$\alpha^{2}+a=\frac{c}{\beta}+\beta$$
$$\frac{b}{\alpha}=\frac{c}{\beta}-\beta.$$
Note that we can eliminate $\beta$ by using the following trick
$$(\alpha^{2}+a)^2-\left(\frac{b}{\alpha}\right)^2=4c$$
substituting $t=\alpha^2$ we obtain the following cubic equation for $t$:
$$t(t+a)^2-4ct-b^{2}=0.$$
Then solving the cubic equation, and selecting any solution we can deduce the values of $\alpha$. Then we need to solve the quadratic equation
$$\beta^{2}+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\beta-c=0.$$
Solving the equation and selecting any of the possible values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, solving the quartic reduces to solving two quadratic equations
$$x^{2}+\alpha x+\beta=0$$ and  $$x^{2}-\alpha x +\frac{c}{\beta}=0.$$
A link to a detailed video lecture is also available.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0J3v0mQItc&ab_channel=Math%2CPhysics%2CEngineering