# special polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I'm searching for a polynomial $f$ of degree 4 with the following property: $f$ and all its derivatives have the maximum number of integer roots.

Concretely formulated:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
 f(x) & = & (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) \\
 f'(x) & = & 4(x-e)(x-f)(x-g) \\
 f''(x) & = & 12(x-h)(x-i) \\
 f'''(x) &= & 24(x-j) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

should be satisfied simultaneously with distinct integers $a,b,c,d$, distinct integers $e,f,g$, disctinct integers $h,i$ and an integer $j$.

My conjecture is that there is no such polynomial. For degree 3, there are solutions. Can anyone either prove this or find a counterexample?

Comment: Must the roots be distinct? If they are counted with multiplicity, $x^4$ will work.

Comment: Any real polynomial with exactly four distinct roots will have three distinct critical points. This is because polynomials are smooth. Therefore, between two zeros, the polymonial either goes up and comes back down or goes down and comes back up.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch the integer part.

Comment: Comparing the desired forms of the derivatives with the derivatives of the previous level we can establish the requirements that $a=b=c=d \pmod 4$ or (wlog) $a=b=c+2=d+2 \pmod 4$; $e=f=g \pmod 3$; and $h=i \pmod 2$. So a reasonable starting point would be a brute force check for non-trivial solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Taking the indicated derivatives, you are asking for integer solutions to $$2j=h+i\\3j=e+f+g\\4j=a+b+c+d\\3hi=ef+eg+fg\\6hi=ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd\\efg=abc+abd+acd+bcd$$  with $a,b,c,d$ distinct as well as $e,f,g$ and $h,i$.  To get $h$ and $i$ rational we need $e^2+f^2+g^2-(ef+eg+fg)$ to be a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like comlicated "solution" but: Try to express every polynomial in universal form:
$\int{(x-a)}dx=\frac{x^2}{2}-ax+b$ ; $\qquad \int{(\frac{x^2}{2}-ax+b)}dx = ...$
and solve system of equations [(conditions of discriminants for real roots)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/quartic-equation-solution-and-conditions-for-real-roots) to prove your conjuncture or find counterexample.